# Can I connect a 12/2 wire to a 10/2 wire to operate garage openers?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I already have 600V 10/2 Wire with ground into my first garage.  It is not connected to the electrical breaker yet. I would like to use it to operate my two garage doors and a few plugs. Am I able to connect the two and what size breaker should I use?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell if this wire is copper or aluminum? (Is the bare wire at the end of the cable coppery or silvery, in other words?)

Comment: just for fyi I think those receptacles are suppose to be protected by a gfi. I'm sure you probably already know but just in case. my friend reminded me when I did my garage. later

Answer (score 4):

### You can, and the combo requires a 20A, single pole breaker

You can always use *larger* require than the minimum required by Code for a given circuit ampacity -- given that the 2017 NEC now requires a 20A circuit for garage receptacles, your plan of extending this circuit with 12/2 is fine.  It will require a 20A, single pole breaker of a suitable type for your existing panel (we'll need to see the labeling on the panel if you want advice on what to buy for a breaker, though), and you'll need to use a torque screwdriver when installing the new wiring (with your main breaker turned off, of course) due to the requirements in 110.14(D) (again, new with the 2017 Code).

### Garage receptacles (save for ceiling ones) need to be GFCI protected

The general garage receptacles will need GFCI protection as well -- I would run the wires to the garage door opener receptacles *first* and then to the first general garage receptacle's location; that way, the GDOs don't wind up on the GFCI rather needlessly while the general receptacles can all be protected by a single GFCI located at the first general garage receptacle box that has the incoming hot + neutral connected to the LINE side, and then you can take the tape off and connect the *outgoing* hot + neutral to the other receptacles to the LOAD side, thus protecting all the garage receptacles with one GFCI.

Comment: When I have installed new breakers I have not turned off the main breaker. I snap in the new breaker with the breaker off, connect the wires, then switch on the breaker. Is this an unsafe practice? What torque are the new standards requiring? I do wear plastic safety glasses which would absorb uv from a large arc.

Comment: @JimStewart -- the main hazard of snapping a breaker in with the bussing live is accidentally poking a live busbar with your finger.  As to the torque requirements of 110.14(D) -- the specification torque is printed on the breaker for breaker lugs, and on the panel labeling for neutral/ground bar terminations and panel main lugs.